# how to get specific value from a string by using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

```
$str="Indore ->Bhopal ,Check-in: Fri, 22 Apr 2016 7:05 AM Singapore Changi Intl Airport - Terminal 2 Krabi ( KBV ) 11:10 AM Arrive";
```

I want to get value of Check-in from the whole string can anyone help me out

Comment: Provided data sample comes as a single string?

Comment: why not extract the string starting from `Check-in`?

Comment: but how do i know when the whole value will end like it will end with  AM

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fR8wO7/1

Comment: http://regexr.com/3dicp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('/Check-in:\s*(.+)\R/', $str, $matches);
```

The result you want is in group 1 (ie. `$matches[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex

```
(?:Check-in:\s*.*AM)$
```

So your code looks like as

```
preg_match_all("/(?:Check-in:\s*.*AM)$/m",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```